# Unable to create unique key constraint with @ManyToMany @JoinTable when entity class name and table name differ

Tags: hibernate, jpa

In Mariadb I have two tables with appropriate indexes:

```
user:
   id
   username (UK_user)

role:
   id
   name (UK_role)
```

With a join table

```
user_role:
   id 
   user_id (FK_user_role_user_id)(ref: user.id)
   role_id (FK_user_role_role_id)(ref: role.id)
   (UK_user_role_user_id_role_id)(columns: role_id, user_id)
```

I have the usual hibernate JPA entities, but because of the need to create a User interface that the entity class implements, then I named it `UserEntity` with `@Table(name='user')`. The `Role` entity is named to match the table.

```java
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(name = "UK_role", columnNames = {"name"})})
public class Role {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
...
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(name = "UK_user", columnNames = {"username"})})
public class UserEntity implements User {
    private Integer id;
    private String username;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_user_role_user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_user_role_role_id"))}, 
            uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(name = "UK_user_role_user_id_role_id", columnNames = {"role_id", "user_id"})})
    private List<Role> roles;
...
```

If I named the entity `User`, and leave out the `name='user'` parameter from the `@Table` annotation, then everything works ok, but like I said, I want `UserEntity` to be an implementation of a `User` interface so they cannot be the same name.

So now I'm getting the following exception when running:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to create unique key constraint (user_id, role_id) on table user_role: database column 'user_id' not found. Make sure that you use the correct column name which depends on the naming strategy in use (it may not be the same as the property name in the entity, especially for relational types)
```

So it does not recognise `user_id` as a column in the `user_role` join table. Why is that? when the column names used in the @UniqueConstraint is the db value.

I tried changing the column names to `UserEntity` and `Roles`, but no joy.

If I remove the uniqueConstrains parameter from the `@JoinTable` annotation, then I get my HSQL testing working. I think my issue is with HSQL on my medium tests, because there is no actual table in the background and the mock db is built using the annotations, so it is expecting something like `user_entity_id`, but that wont work when deploying my application. I would have thought the `@Table(name='user')` annotation at the class level would have told HSQL and JPA that the table should be called 'user'.

Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: I think you should simply define the `joinColumns` field of the `@JoinTable`, I imagine as: `joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_user_role_user_id")) }`.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos I tried that, and just letting the constraints be handled by the db, but it still complained that column user_id could not be found.

Comment: So I fixed it by declaring the @Entity name `@Entity(name = "User")`. I guess this forces HSQL and JPA to assume the entity name as `User` and with @Table(name = "user")` it can properly match the entity with the table, while at the same time I can use `UserEntity` as the class name in the rest of my code. It also means that any named or native query definition will use `SELECT u FROM User u .....`. I'm happy it works, so I will press on, but if anyone can explain why this works then it would be really appreciated.